# Could not ping vmware2.domain.local - observium

Tags: debian, turnkeylinux.org, observium

Observium CE 0.15.6.6430

Turnkey linux 14.0

When I tried to add a device, I will get the message " Could not ping vmware2.domain.local"

But I can ping that hostname from observium's CLI

```
fping  -t 3 -c 1 -q vmware2.domain.local
vmware2.domain.local : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/1/0%, min/avg/max = 0.11/0.11/0.11
```

How do I solve this? There's no error on in /opt/observium/logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known "issue". Observium docs suggest that this NOT be enabled by default (security concerns) and instead use the commandline to add devices. You can manually enable this if you want (see the [TurnKey Issue Tracker](https://github.com/turnkeylinux/tracker/issues/488#issuecomment-153762770))